# modify browsers default transfer progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page on my website where the user changes their info ( personal details, profile image, background image, ... ).
When the user clicks on the submit button, there is loading and at the bottom-left of the screen there is a place showing how much of the transfer is done in percentage (is this done by default by browser?).

I was wondering is there any way to display this loading percentage better on the screen (more centered) and maybe change its appearance a bit too?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly. That progress display is part of the web browser interface -- it's not part of your web page, and you cannot affect its appearance.

It's possible to entirely replace the form submission process with a Javascript substitute, but this is rather complex, and is unlikely to be appropriate for your use case.